# Scala - identical method for different input classes

Tags: scala

Imagine the following class

```
class A{
    def update(x: Vector, y: Vector): Vector = {
        x + 0.5 * y
    }

    def update(x: Matrix, y: Matrix): Matrix = {
        x + 0.5 * y
    }
}
```

The only difference between both methods is the input type. What would be the correct way of unifying these methods and avoid duplicating code in Scala?

Comment: what's a `Matrix`?

Comment: I'm working with Breeze's DenseMatrix and DenseVector, but I'm wondering whats the general solution for this problem in Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend defining a typeclass for common algebraic operations:

```
trait Algebra[A] {
  def plus(x: A, y: A): A
  def timesScalar(x: A, d: Double): A
}

implicit val vectorAlgebra = new Algebra[Vector] {
  def plus(x: Vector, y: Vector): Vector = x + y
}

// ... same for Matrix ...

def update[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit alg: Algebra[A]): A = {
  alg.plus(x, alg.timesScalar(y, 0.5))
}
```

You can also look into [simulacrum](https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum) if you want to easily generate some syntactical sugar for the typeclass so you could in theory do something simpler like:

```
def update[A : Algebra](x: A, y: A): A = {
  x + (y * 0.5)
}
```

An entirely different approach would be more OO-based, and make a common trait like `Algebraic` that both `Vector` and `Matrix` could inherit from. But that's tougher when they're coming from other libraries, so you end up having to wrap them in your own classes. And then you hit complications with F-bounded polymorphism... I'd just go with the typeclass.